# Regular expression to match phone numbers with country codes

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the regular expression I use to match phone numbers like:

```
00 00 00 00 00
00 00 0 00 00 00 00
+00 0 00 00 00 00

(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})\s+(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})\s+(+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})
```

I have tried to include it into my javascript but It's not really working

```
if(document.maj_profil.phone.value.search(/^\(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\)\s+\(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\)\s+\(+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\)/) == -1)
    {
    displayDialog('wrong phone format')
        }
```

Comment: Surely those \\\( \\\)'s are wrong? In your examples there are no brackets around the phone numbers.

Comment: Does your user have to enter 1 phone number or does he have to enter all 3?

Comment: only one, but there is 3 possible format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Where you have your alternative formats listed like:

   ```
   (...)\s+(...)\s+(...)
   ```

   Change that to use the `|` (OR) operator:

   ```
   (...)|(...)|(...)
   ```
2. Don't escape the parentheses. `\(` and `\)` should be simply `(` and `)`.
3. In your third group the `+` at the beginning should be escaped with a backslash:

   ```
   (\+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
\d\d(\s+\d\d){4}|(\d\d\s+\d\d\s+\d|\+\s+\d)\d\d(\s+\d\d){3}
```

which means:

```
\d\d(\s+\d\d){4}    // 00 00 00 00 00

|                   // OR

(                   // (
  \d\d\s+\d\d\s+\d  //    00 00 0
  |                 //    OR
  \+\s+\d           //    + 0
)                   // )
\d\d(\s+\d\d){3}    // 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript, you have escaped all the brackets. Do you want them to behave as capturing groups, or do you want to match actual brackets in the string?

Also use test instead of search. test returns true or false, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the parenthesis turns them into literals. Try it without the escapes:

```
/^(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})\s+(\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})\s+(\d{2}\s+\d\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2})/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var re = /^\+?(\d{1,2} ?)+$/g
var phone = "00 00 00 00 00"; //"00 00 00 00 00x"; 
if(!re.test(phone))
    alert("wrong phone pattern");
```