# Capture phones with area code + number or country + area + number

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match phone numbers with country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566544/regular-expression-to-match-phone-numbers-with-country-codes)

Currently I have this regex do validate/capture phone numbers: `^(\+?(?<country>\d{1,3}?) ?)?(\(?0?(?<area>\d{2})\)? ?)?(?<phone>9?\d{4}[-. ]?\d{4})$`

It accepts numbers like `88888888`, `8888-8888`, `8888.8888`, `11 8888-8888`, `(11) 88888888`, `+22 (21) 8888-8888` and every combination in this format.

The problem is: when I pass the area code without contry code (like this: `(11) 8888-8888` or `11 8888-8888` or even `1188888888`) it gets the area code part (11) as the country code, and leaves the area code empty.

How could I do something like `country + area + phone` OR`area + phone` but NOT `country + phone`? Without doing something like this:

`^(((\(?0?(?<area>\d{2})\)? ?)?|(\+?(?<country>\d{1,3}?) ?)?(\(?0?(?<area>\d{2})\)? ?)?)(?<phone>9?\d{4}[-. ]?\d{4})$`

Wich is (area+phone|country+area+phone) but the area and the country regexp gets repeated twice.

Comment: Which regexp flavor do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is an ambiguity between a country code with two digits and an area code with two digits. When the regexp hits this case, it considers the area code as a country code since country code is placed first and area code is optional.

**SOLUTION #1 : Using a negative lookahead (?!...)**

To solve this problem, one could tell the regexp to **ignore** two digits country code followed by a phone number. In order to keep the regexp small enough (thus not too complicated), it's possible to give just the beginning of a phone number.

Here is the negative lookahead to use: `(?!9?\d{4})`

A two digits number is qualified as a country code ONLY if it is not followed by the start of a phone number (`9?\d{4}`).

The final regexp is :

```
^(\+?(?<country>\d{1,3}?) ?(?!9?\d{4}))?(\(?0?(?<area>\d{2})\)? ?)?(?<phone>9?\d{4}[-. ]?\d{4})$
```

**SOLUTION #2: Templating the regular expression**

IMO, if a flavor could allow to build a regular expression with templates, it would be a powerful feature. Well this feature doesn't exist in any flavor I know of.

But there is a workaround. The following code is a snippet written in C#

```
(...)
string country = "(\\+?(?<country>\\d{1,3}?) ?)";
string area = "(\\(?0?(?<area>\\d{2})\\)? ?)";
string phone = "(?<phone>9?\\d{4}[-. ]?\\d{4})";
string final_regexp = String.Format("^{1}{2}{3}|{2}?{3}$", country, area, phone);
(...)
```